How to logging Preferences library
On my esp32 project, I use Preferences.h to store some values over rebooting.
I have the issue that mypref.begin("nameSpc", false); returns 0 in one case, but works in a other part of the program.
So I'm looking for debugging and found some things like ESP_LOGI ESP_LOGE.
How I use this mechanic agains Preferences.h / mypref.begin()?
I don't understand this and have not found any examples that take me to AHA!

oh, my goodness...
it's easier as it's look's. To have some debugging output over Serial you must:
Tools->Core Debug Level -> verbose
and
#if (!PLATFORMIO)
  // Enable Arduino-ESP32 logging in Arduino IDE
  #ifdef CORE_DEBUG_LEVEL
    #undef CORE_DEBUG_LEVEL
  #endif
  #ifdef LOG_LOCAL_LEVEL
    #undef LOG_LOCAL_LEVEL
  #endif

  #define CORE_DEBUG_LEVEL 4
  #define LOG_LOCAL_LEVEL CORE_DEBUG_LEVEL
#endif  

#include <esp32-hal-log.h>

Thats all, now i've got what i' looking for ;-)
Can be closed!

"Can be closed!" No, this is not how this site works, please take the [tour] to learn more. This is not a forum. -- Instead, mark your answer as "accepted" so that others seeking for help will notice this directly in the list of search results. -- However, if you think your question and answer are not worth to be kept, simply delete it.

Is your code working properly now?
